# Convert JSONL to JSON

Tags: json, linux, jsonlines

Is there a way to convert `JSONL` to `JSON` in Linux with the full `JSONL` file depth? I found some methods based on `jq` but they don't work with full depth of `JSONL` file

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific; what do you mean with "full JSONL file depth"?

Answer (score 0):

I am quite confused as to what you want to do. But when it comes to jq, normally I process things line by line, with each line being an atomic `JSON` object. Something like

```
cat file | jq some-options 'some commands' > output.txt
```

Sometimes I get the output in `tsv` format and pipe it into `awk`. `jq` is very friendly with line-by-line objects.

To convert a large `JSON` list into line by line format, just parse the large object in any programming language, and serialize the inner objects back to json line by line.

But if you have already parsed the large object, I suggest you do the required processing you want to do in `jq` directly, without serializing the inner objects back...

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "[" >$1.json
perl -pe 's/$/,/' <$1 >>$1.json
echo "]" >>$1.json
```